# Applying for a Greece Schengen visa too late: possibilities and consequences?

Tags: schengen, greece, history, schengen-visas

I am applying for a visa to attend a conference in Greece. My nationality is from a country that requires [prior consultation](https://www.mfa.gr/missionsabroad/images/visas/english/C_Annex16PriorConsultation_en.pdf), so the visa process takes three weeks. However, I submitted the application just 11 days before the flight.

Now, two questions:

1. Assume that the Greek embassy finishes the paperwork and I meet all the conditions, but they finish it after my conference. Do they still issue the visa?
2. If the visa is issued after my conference, I will obviously not fly to Greece. I can [still go to other Schengen countries](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/13362/should-my-first-trip-be-to-the-country-which-issued-my-schengen-visa) within the 3-month visa period, and possibly the Embassy of Greece might get angry about this case and consider this as a negative point for further visa applications. However, do all other Schengen countries put me in such a `red-list` if I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Possibly not, but that is their call. They *should* conclude that the premise of the trip is no longer applicable.
2. Schengen visa are not always granted for 3 months validity. They *may*  be issued just for the days of the planned visit. This is more common for first-time applicants.

   - A single-entry visa should be used for the premise of the application.
   - A multiple-entry visa should be used *first* for the premise of the application, afterwards it can be used for other trips within the duration and validity.