# Schengen visa confusion

Tags: france, schengen-visas, visa-expiration

I received my Schengen visa today from the French Embassy. I wrote in my application that I will stay for 14 days. They gave me 1 month (valid from 23-10-18 until 21-11-18) but on the side it says *duration of stay 14 days*. Can I stay for only 14 days?

Now I regret that I did not make it for 20 days. I had no idea that they would just allow me 14 days. I thought that if it's valid for one month I could stay for one month. Also, is it okay if I change my mind and stay only 3 days in Paris and go to Rome for 5 days?

Comment: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/13362/should-my-first-trip-be-to-the-country-which-issued-my-schengen-visa

Comment: You should observe the visa restrictions scrupulously. This will improve your ability to get future visas.

Comment: @Traveller What is the linked question related to this question?

Answer (score 7):

You asked for fourteen days and they have given you fourteen days. That seems reasonable to me. They've also given you a little flexibility in your travel dates.

Whilst some changes to your itinerary are acceptable, changing your itinerary such that you should really have applied through the Italian authorities will look like visa shopping, and the immigration authorities can take a dim view of it.

If you want to go to Rome keep it to just a couple of days this time. I suspect that Paris will keep you busy enough for two weeks that a side trip to Rome will become a distraction.