# Can I go through a flight from Delhi to Berlin via Helsinki if I have mentioned Germany as the "member state of first entry"?

Tags: visas, schengen

In my Schengen VISA application, I have mentioned Germany as "member state of first entry" and provided the itinerary of a Lufthansa flight which goes from Delhi to Berlin via Frankfurt, but due to the cost factor, I want to book Finnair now which transits through Helsinki. My understanding is that since I am entering the Schengen area in Helsinki I will have to go through immigration there.

Will it create a problem because I have mentioned Germany as "member state of first entry" or will it be fine?

Can the immigration officer look at my VISA application?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Should my first trip be to the country which issued my Schengen Visa?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/13362/should-my-first-trip-be-to-the-country-which-issued-my-schengen-visa). Go ahead. Plans change and this is not a **material** change. Whether the immigration officer can see your visa application or not (actually he can’t) is irrelevant. You don’t have to hide anything or lie when asked. This is nothing at all

Comment: Note that "visa" is just an ordinary English word, not an acronym. It doesn't need to be written in all caps, or even capitalized.

Answer (score 2):

This is not a problem. You said you were going to Germany and you are still going to Germany. You just booked a cheaper ticket. If the immigration officer asks about it, you can just show them your onward ticket to Berlin.