# Travel to other Schengen countries with Type D Germany national visa

Tags: schengen

I have been issued Germany National Type D visa but it is never used (no port of entry). Can I travel to other Schengen areas without going to Germany at all on that Visa?

Comment: @Traveller: I don't really think that's a duplicate, since in this case the OP has not even used the national visa to go to the country that issued it. (And the proposed original only has downvoted answers, so it's probably not all that helpful anyway).

Comment: @Rahuk Aggarwal The answer might depend on several questions including why you want to go to another Schengen country (eg on your way to Germany?), why you’ve not used your D visa so far, and whether you intend to do so for the purpose it was issued. This may help https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/13362/should-my-first-trip-be-to-the-country-which-issued-my-schengen-visa but I think you’ll need to expand your question to get a more meaningful answer