# Schengen visitor visa main destination

Tags: schengen-visas, itineraries

My girlfriend just got a Schengen visa from France.

Is there any consequences if we do not visit France and only visit other countries?

Was planning to visit France next weekend, but the weather looks terrible. Got a Switzerland planned for April.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Should my first trip be to the country which issued my Schengen Visa?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/13362/should-my-first-trip-be-to-the-country-which-issued-my-schengen-visa). If she has a single entry visa, it is definitely not advisable to use it to go to another country entirely