# I want to visit Italy, Switzerland and Spain so which visa and can we land in Italy and leave from Spain?

Tags: indian-citizens, schengen-visas, applications, itineraries

I'm from India.

So my question is  we are going Europe for 15 days and we want to land in Italy and then we will go to Switzerland and our last destination is Spain so which type so Schengen visa is required and can we take our flight from Spain.
But we are landing in Italy first?

Comment: Take the visa from the embassy of the country you are planning to stay the longest at. If you're staying equal length at the three countries then take it from the embassy of the entry country..

Comment: No problem with entering the zone in one country and leaving from an other.

Comment: Related question https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/13362/should-my-first-trip-be-to-the-country-which-issued-my-schengen-visa

Answer (score 4):

You may arrive and depart the Schengen area from any airport you wish.

You should be sure to choose the correct country to apply for the Schengen visa: that is, either the country where you will spend the most days, the country which is your *main destination*, or if there is no main destination, e.g. you spend an equal number of days in every country, then the first country of your itinerary.