# Can I use a standard tourist visa as a transit visa for UK/Schengen areas?

Tags: visas, uk, schengen, transit, international-travel

I am traveling to Poland and most of my flight options pass via London, or other Schengen countries. I will have a UK visa since my next destination is Birmingham. I won't be leaving the airport area in the layovers. Do I require a transit visa in this scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don’t need a UK transit visa if you already hold a valid UK visitor visa.

See also [Should my first trip be to the country which issued my Schengen Visa?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/13362/should-my-first-trip-be-to-the-country-which-issued-my-schengen-visa)

Comment: @Rutwick Gangurde If I were you I’d consider travelling to Poland via a Schengen country. That way, if your U.K. visa is refused, it won’t complicate all your plans. There are cheap flights to the UK from many Schengen countries including Poland, and (unlike Schengen) UKVI specifically advise against booking your flight before you get the visa decision

Comment: That makes sense. However, with respect to the UKVI advice, how can I apply for the visa unless I show them my flight bookings? What does decision mean?

Comment: @RutwickGangurde: The point of the advice is that you _are not supposed_ to show flight bookings in your visa application. The checklists explicitly tell you to leave them out.

Comment: @Rutwick Gangurde See section 4 of the UK guidance on supporting documents https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/549692/Visitor_Supporting_Documents_Guide_-_English_version.pdf - flight bookings are specifically stated as not required in support of the application. ‘Decision’ means approval or refusal.