# Visa query for Croatia with Schengen visa from Switzerland

Tags: schengen-visas, croatia

I am an Indian passport holder, travelling to Croatia. I am first visiting Vienna and then to Croatia.  But I have Schengen visa from Switzerland. Should this be ok?

Comment: What type of Schengen visa (How many days and entries). You can look at [this question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/13362/50234) to see if you can visit Austria on Swiss issued Schengen visa.

Comment: Please read the linked question. Entering Schengen at Austria instead of Switzerland is not surprising, as they are adjacent and the border agents understand better airfares might be worth a small detour. Your problem is the mismatch between your actual itinerary (which you may be asked about) and the one you supplied with the visa application.

Comment: OP has not returned to clarify. Putting on hold for now.