# Multiple Entry Schengen Visa: France or Netherlands?

Tags: schengen, france, schengen-visas, netherlands, multiple-entry

I currently hold a Tier-4 UK student visa, but will be looking at applying for a multiple entry Schengen visa to be able to visit my mother, who's moving to the Netherlands end of this year. However, before that my friends and I are planning a trip to France.

Will it be easier for me to apply for the Schengen via French embassy, and in my application say that I am also planning to use it afterwards to enter Netherlands on a monthly basis, or shall I go through Dutch embassy, to ensure that I'll get the 3-year visa I require?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Also, depending on your personal circumstances (citizenship, travel history, wealth, ties to the UK...) it may be easier to ask for a single-entry visa for France first, and later to ask for a multiple-entry visa for the Netherlands. Note also that counting on a 3-year visa may (again, depending on your circumstances) be placing the bar quite high...

Answer (score 1):

Since your mother is not yet living in the Netherlands you don’t really have a strong premise for applying for a Dutch visa.

Schengen rules require you to apply to the country that will be your main destination according to your itinerary. If you could prove you’ll be visiting your mother regularly because she is already living in the Netherlands, you could apply to the Dutch authorities, include your proposed French trip in your itinerary, and (assuming your application was approved) use your Dutch-issued multiple entry visa to visit France.

Your proposed French trip currently appears to be your only provable premise, so you’ll need to apply to France.

Related question [Should my first trip be to the country which issued my Schengen Visa?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/13362/should-my-first-trip-be-to-the-country-which-issued-my-schengen-visa)

Comment: When you post an answer, can you please delete the comment it is based on? This time I did it for you.