# Schengen Visa | Port of Entry

Tags: visas, schengen, transit, indian-citizens, cdg

I have a valid Schengen Visa which is issued by Austrian Embassy. I have invitation from Austria from a relative & got my EVE verification done from Austria. Also, I submitted the flight itinery to Vienna during my Visa submission. Now, I have a change in plan & wanted to land in Paris first, spend 3 days in Paris & fly to Rome then & Austria thereafter. Since my relative is sponsoring me, I have the invitation letter saying they will be taking care of my expenses including my accommodation during my visit in Austria. So I dont have any Hotel bookings in Austria. But, I will have Hotel bookings in Paris. Is there any chance that my entry to France will be denied since my port of Entry is Paris instead of Austria ? 
Thanks for the help in advance.
Robins

Comment: Is your visa single or multiple entry? Was your original itinerary solely Austria? https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/13362/should-my-first-trip-be-to-the-country-which-issued-my-schengen-visa

Comment: I am an Indian citizen and will be planning to travel from India. I got multiple entry visa. My plan is to travel to Austria after couple of days in Paris & Rome each.

Answer (score 2):

The change in port of entry will not in itself cause problems.

What I can see might be a problem is that you're now going to several destinations where your sponsor is not. If the sponsorship actually played any role in deciding to grant you a visa, that might be seen as a major change, and those are not allowed.

Comment: All of this is true. It might additionally be noted that a French border guard sitting in a booth with a line before him doesn't have any immediate way to check the circumstances of a visa application processed by Austria. If he thinks something smells fishy he might pull you aside for secondary processing and then he _might_ (though this is not certain) be able to request some information from the Austrians -- but this won't happen unless he has a reason to be suspicious in the first place.

Comment: @HenningMakholm isn't some of the information available in the VIS? Article 18 of VIS regulation says that application data (including any guarantor info if supplied by applicant) is available for verification by the competent authorities who carry out external border checks

Comment: @Ozzy: Hmm, yes -- I wasn't aware that these rules were public. Though it doesn't seem to say that the system contains the precise itinerary applied with, nor how much importance an invitation had for the decision making.

Comment: @HenningMakholm yeah they don't seem to be very well known in here. True. It doesn't contain planned itinerary. But he/she might face some questioning if this is consulted and they see that A) port of entry has changed and B) new itinerary does not include the guarantor for the beginning of the trip. If I were OP I'd carry some solid proof of funds. By the way, you're welcome for the new reading material haha!

Comment: If you were granted a visa with the invitation of a guarantor, is it mandatory that the guarantor accompany you through out your travel through schengen region ?

Comment: @RobinsChacko I doubt that is the case. If I were you, I would try to at least carry a good 3 months of bank statements in case of questioning at Paris. Or you can avoid any hassle by keeping Austria as your port of entry and THEN traveling around. But then again I am a very risk-averse guy...