# UK Issued 1951 Blue Travel Document - Can you travel throughout Schengen without a visa if entering a visa free country?

Tags: schengen-visas, transit-visas, visa-free-entry, refugees

Planning a tourism trip (< 90 days) with a friend who has the 1951 Blue Travel Document issued via the UK. On our last trip we went to Italy, which permits her to enter without a visa for a short term stay.

Some other country require a visa to enter (France, Spain, etc). If we fly into Italy and then train or fly to other Schengen countries, will she be allowed to enter? Can we fly out of a country like Spain etc that is Schengen as long as we enter via a country like Italy? Italy will give her a stamp on entry, is that considered a valid Schengen visa for display if we are in other Schengen countries?

Comment: For completeness, is the Travel Document valid for at least three months after the date you intend to leave the Schengen area?

Comment: Yes @Traveller it is

Answer (score 8):

> If we fly into Italy and then train or fly to other Schengen countries, will she be allowed to enter?

> Can we fly out of a country like Spain etc that is Schengen as long as we enter via a country like Italy?

**NO**, not at all

If you don't have the required permission to enter a country, entering that country is illegal, even through Schengen, which merely abolishes border controls, and not the validity of national law of the different member states.

> Italy will give her a stamp on entry, is that considered a valid Schengen visa for display if we are in other Schengen countries?

An entry stamp is just a record of you entering, this is **not** a visa and doesn't give you more access than you already legally have. Even if that would, an Italian border guard could never issue you a French/Spanish visa.

But you are free to go to any country you are allowed to enter visa-free (provided you don't enter any country you don't have proper permission to enter, even for transit)

Comment: There's an official source somewhere that would support this answer.  I don't have time to look for it now but someone ought to.

Comment: What about is we get a visa for one country. Can it be used for all of Schengen ?

Comment: @bebop1010 See https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/13362/should-my-first-trip-be-to-the-country-which-issued-my-schengen-visa