# Will my second Spanish Schengen Visa get rejected if I didn't follow the itinerary first time?

Tags: indian-citizens, visa-refusals, schengen-visas, spain

I had a 3 month multi-entry Schengen visa issued by Spain. When I applied for it, it was suppose to be a business trip but later trip was cancelled but I still had a visa so I was like why to waste.

My first port of entry stamp was from Frankfurt from where I took a bus to a Ryan Budget Domestic Airport nearby to take an internal flight to Spain (no stamping happened in Spain). From Spain after few nights, I went to few more countries ensuring not to spend as many days as I did in Spain.

Eventually I went to London and then came back to Frankfurt (technically my second entry into EU on Spanish issued visa) to pick my bags and exited in few hours to America.

So technically, during my first visit of multi-entry, I did spend max days in Spain. But the thing is my passport doesn't have a Spanish stamp (internal flights, no border control) hence two entry stamps from Germany, one (first) exit stamp from Sweden (while going to London) and one (second) from Germany.

Now, I am applying for another Schengen visa from Spain. Should I add proof (flights and train tickets) stating I did stay maximum time in Spain (because stamps might tell a different story) or do they have a way to track internal flights and already know that or they won't care (I have good financial background and have travelled 20 countries)?

p.s.: I am an Indian (country with higher scrutiny for visa than normal)

Comment: People can enter or exit the Schengen Area anywhere they want, and many do. Entering or exiting through other countries than the one which issued the visa is a non-event. They’ll be happy you left in time. No point in telling them more unless they ask (and for Schengen they usually don’t ask anything).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Should my first trip be to the country which issued my Schengen Visa?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/13362/should-my-first-trip-be-to-the-country-which-issued-my-schengen-visa)

Comment: Suppose you had spent **the whole time** in Spain, but flown through Frankfurt.  You would not have any Spanish stamps.  And as you probably know, Lufthansa has a significant business in long-haul flights connecting to airports all around Europe.  There are surely lots of people with Schengen visas from all over the Schengen area who have stamps only from Germany.  The same is true for other countries with large airlines (France and the Netherlands come to mind).  The fact that none of your stamps came from Spain is not going to be a problem.

Comment: how do "they" know I did spend *the whole time* in Spain

Comment: @dragosrsupercool they don't!

Comment: There are a few places (mostly in Eastern Europe) where they apparently actively track hotel reservations and will threaten to cancel your visa if you don’t go to the places you said you would (or at least stay in their country ally least as long as you told them you would). But this is quite the exception, and I’ve never heard anything similar about Spain or any of the Western EU countries (the countries doing so are supposedly trying to fight against visa shopping where people apply from “easier” countries but do not intend to go there).