# How much i need in order to be granted the Schengen visa?

Tags: schengen, schengen-visas, money, interview

How much i need in my bank account in order to be granted the Schengen visa?

Probably i will apply for a single entry visa, because it will be my first Schengen visa apply. I want to travel Czech Republic, maybe Slovenia as a tourist. I will continue my education in Romania for a semester through Erasmus+ program. So I will apply in Romania. During the visa apply period, I will have Romania national visa (I'm from Azerbaijan) and temporary residence permit.

Comment: The answer will depend upon a) what kind of visa you wish to obtain, and b) which Schengen country will receive and process your application. It may also depend on c) the location where you make (or file) your visa application.

Comment: Is the Czech Republic the main destination of your proposed trip? You should apply to the Schengen country which is your main destination. Review the answer to this question: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/39468/at-which-embassy-should-i-apply-for-a-schengen-visa-when-staying-a-few-days-in-s

Comment: @DavidSupportsMonica edited

Comment: It is not (just) what you have in your bank, it is also what you earn and need every month, so it is unlikely we can give you a number.

Comment: @Willeke 800 Euro scholarship/month

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reference subsistence amounts are published here https://ec.europa.eu/home-affairs/sites/homeaffairs/files/e-library/documents/policies/borders-and-visas/schengen/docs/handbook-annex_25.pdf

For the Czech Republic it appears to be around the equivalent of 1.100 CZK per day of stay (for stays less than 30 days). For Slovenia, if you don’t have secured means of subsistence (family, paid accommodation within a tourist package, etc...), the daily means of subsistence is fixed at the equivalent of EUR 70.

You should keep in mind that being able to demonstrate the required figure is not the only aspect - proportionality of expenditure to earnings/savings is important too, as is demonstrating stable financial circumstances.