# Schengen visa application

Tags: schengen-visas, france, tourist-visas, switzerland, vfs-global

I have visa appointment at VFS Switzerland for Schengen tourist visa. Both my entry and exit point is in Paris. Below is my brief itinerary:

1. Land in Paris and stay there for 2 days.
2. Go to switzerland via train for 5 days.
3. Go to Rome via train for 3 days.
4. Fly to Brussels for 3 days.
5. Go back to Paris to catch the flight back to India.

My concern is will there be any issues in getting the visa as I have applied it from Switzerland but both my entry and exit are from Paris?

Comment: Related question https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/39468/at-which-embassy-should-i-apply-for-a-schengen-visa-when-staying-a-few-days-in-s

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this case the point of entry is not important.

Important is only that your **main destination** (where you will be staying the longest) is as stated in your application.

In this case Switzerland (5 days), the others each 3 days.

You can enter/exit the Schengen Area from any country (in this case France).

---

Only when the **main destination** can not be determined, would the country of the port of entry to the Schengen Area be responsible for the issuing of the visa.

Sample:

- France 3 days (planed port of entry at the time of application)
- Switzerland, Italy and Belgium **each** 5 days

  - no **single** country has the largest amount of days

then France, as country of the port of entry, should be chosen because no **main destination** can be determined based on length of stay in days.

---

> Visa Code
> **Article 5 Member State competent for examining and deciding on an application**
>
> 1. The Member State competent for examining and deciding on an application for a uniform visa shall be:
>    (a) the Member State whose territory constitutes the **sole destination** of the visit(s);
>    (b) if the visit includes more than one destination, or if several separate visits are to be carried out within a period of two months, the Member State whose territory constitutes the **main destination** of the visit(s) **in terms of the length of stay**, counted in days, or the purpose of stay; or
>    (c) *if no main destination can be determined*, the Member State whose **external border the applicant intends to cross in order to enter the territory of the Member States**.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I have asked few guys and each of them gave a different answer. So, it was getting confusing for me

Comment: You may want to add “in this case”. The point of entry can be important and is explicitly mentioned in article 5(1)(c) of the Schengen visa code, right below 5(1)(b) where this main destination rule is defined.

Comment: What does the said article mean? Can I not enter and exit from Paris if I have Switzerland visa? I am not able to find the exact article

Comment: @RohitPannu You can enter the Schengen Area in any country.

Comment: @Relaxed Have adapted text as suggested, with a sample.

Comment: @RohitPannu the article means that _in cases where there is no "main destination," the visa application should be submitted to the country where the traveler will enter the Schengen area._  That provision does not apply to your present application because Switzerland is your main destination.