# Entry into countries in Schengen Area with a visa issued by Spain

Tags: visas, schengen

I'm from Pakistan, and I have received a Schengen visa issued by the Spanish Embassy in the UAE. Can I enter the Schengen Area via Finland, or any other country on the Schengen visa country list?

Comment: Do you have a multiple entry Schengen Visa. Kindly refer to this question: http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/9646/does-a-multiple-entry-schengen-visa-allow-visiting-other-schengen-countries-late

Comment: In theory, it may be possible, depending on the specifics of your visa and on your travel plans and travel history. Without this information, it's not really possible to answer your question, which is probably why it is receiving votes to close as "unclear." One of those is mine, but if you edition your question to include that information, I will retract my close vote.

Comment: I think the question is quite clear for the people who hold such credentials and therefore face similar problems.

Answer (score 2):

**Yes**, if that travel is covered by the premise which you filed when you applied for the visa. If you told them that you are a business traveler and that you want to visit many different Schengen countries, and if they gave you a multiple entry visa on that basis, you can use the visa to visit Finland after going to Spain.

**No**, if you gave a different premise with your application. If you told them that you want to go to Spain, you should use the visa to go to Spain and not to Finland.

Comment: On a wide array this answer is right, but what if you have a multiple entry visa without asking, and you already made the trip you detailed in visa app, can u visit other Schengen countries if the visa is still valid? Yes, you can, and yes, embassies give multiple visa without asking, depending on the previous visa history and tonne of other factors.

Comment: The purpose of travel need not be the same. If the Spanish visa has been issued for tourism, and is also valid for a trip to Sweden, the trip to Sweden can be a business trip or a trip for medical treatment or for any other purpose allowed under sort-stay visas.

Comment: It also depends a bit on the country of arrival (in your case Finland). My first arrival in 2010 was restricted to enter only the country who issued the visa. Once I entered then of course based on the type of Schengen visa I can visit freely other EU member states. So, please check current regulations for Finland.