# Can I get a multiple-entry short-stay France Schengen visa and travel to Romania for a few days?

Tags: schengen, france, multiple-entry, romania

I am an Indian and I am planning to attend a conference in Paris. I intend to stay in Paris for the longest duration of my trip. (9 nights). I then planned to travel to a few places in the Schengen region before going to Romania to visit a friend. My return flight is from Budapest back to India.

I have never traveled in the Schengen area before. Would it be possible for me to get a multiple-entry short-stay France Schengen visa to travel outside of Schengen and return back to it?

If I am coming back to Budapest just to board the flight, would that still be a good reason enough for the embassy to issue me a multiple-entry visa?

Comment: Hmmm, the question which my question is believed to be the duplicated of, seems to mention that the OP doesn't want to travel to the issuing country. Are you sure this is a duplicate?

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate of the question @Newton proposed. Perhaps of a different question here, but not that.

Comment: Not an exact duplicate but the answers might help out https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/9646/does-a-multiple-entry-schengen-visa-allow-visiting-other-schengen-countries-late

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the use case that the *two-entry* visa is supposed to solve, so if you present your entire itinerary (including Romania and the return via Budapest) in your application to the French consulate, they should be willing to issue a two-entry visa that allows what you want to do.

Note, though, that if your return journey is by plane from, say, Bucharest with just a short layover in Budapest with your baggage checked through, you may not need to enter the Schengen area on the way back at all, and then a single-entry visa will suffice as far as Schengen is concerned. This will *not* be to your advantage, because then you would need a separate visa for Romania whereas holders of two-entry Schengen visas can enter Romania without a specificially Romanian visa. (And the entry into Romania doesn't count as one of the "two entries").

So it would be in your interest to structure your plans such that you do some real visiting inside the Schengen area *after* Romania.

Comment: "if your return journey is by plane from, say, Bucharest with just a short layover in Budapest, you may not need to enter the Schengen area on the way back at all (that is, you can stay in the non-Schengen zone of the airport), and then a single-entry visa will suffice": no it won't. See https://www.mae.ro/en/node/2040.  The visa must be issued for two or multiple entries. @BhargavPonnapalli A single-entry Schengen visa is not valid for entry into Romania.  Neither is a dual-entry visa where both entries have been used.

Comment: @phoog: That's what the rest of the paragraph explains. What I'm trying to say is that if his plans don't involve entering the Schengen area on the way home, the _French_ consulate will not think he has a need for a two-entry visa as far as they are concerned, and _then_ he will need to get a separate Romanian visa.

Comment: Is there a good chance that I won't get an MEV if I just want to go to Budapest to board the flight? Is the reason not good enough to request an MEV?

Comment: @BhargavPonnapalli: The changes of getting a _multiple_ entry visa at all are very slim. The best you can hope for without a Schengen travel history and a reason to make frequent visits to the area is a _two_ entry visa.

Comment: Fair enough.  I just found the way it was worded a little confusing.  @BhargavPonnapalli if the French consulate is inclined to do you a favor, they'll issue a dual-entry visa.  If you're really lucky, they might issue a multiple-entry visa.  It probably won't hurt your application for you to ask.  But you should prepare for the very real possibility that they will issue a single-entry visa, and allow enough time to apply for a Romanian visa in that event.

Comment: I see. So if they want to issue a single entry visa when I requested for a double entry, would I have to apply all over again? Or it will it just be a small change in their part?

Comment: @BhargavPonnapalli: If you present a reasonable itinerary where _the Shengen part_ requires two entries, you can normally expect to get two entries. Where things begin to depend on favors is if your itinerary _can_ be done with a single entry into Schengen and a separate Romanian visa.