# Passport control going from London to Brussels or Amsterdam

Tags: schengen, schengen-visas, eurostar

I have a multiple-entry French Schengen visa (valid for almost 5 months, allowing 90 days of stay), which I have used twice to enter France, using up a total of 10 days. I am now considering traveling to Belgium or the Netherlands.

1. If traveling by Eurostar, would I present my passport to the border police of France, or would it be the authorities of the destination country, say Belgium or the Netherlands? I am asking this question because it seems that there are Eurostar services that do not call anywhere in France - they proceed directly across the border to Brussels.
2. Irrespective of the first question, am I allowed to travel to other Schengen countries, possibly by air, after using my French Schengen visa twice to enter France?

Comment: Your question 2 is answered [here](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/9646/3221).

Comment: For question 1, probably yes, but that shouldn't be a problem considering the answer to 2. You should **bring** your passport even if it isn't checked at an inner-EU border.

Comment: I believe the edit by @dda has changed the meaning of my first question. I'm aware that there is Passport Control at St. Pancras, and meant to ask which country exercises it: France, irrespective of the destination, or the destination country (which may be Belgium or the Netherlands). I've edited the question to clarify.

Comment: @SgrA it's the same as would happen at a regular border.  Imagine a train that traveled from Belgrade to Vienna without stopping in Hungary.  It would still be processed by Hungarian border guards when it entered the Schengen area in Hungary.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. The Schengen border controls at St Pancras are manned by the *French* Border Police only (per [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Juxtaposed_controls#Eurostar)).  The vast majority of Eurostar trains to Brussels also stop in Lille, and it is presumably not felt necessary to separate out Belgium-bound passengers for separate inspection.
2. Provided that you meet the normal requirements for entering the Schengen Zone (the same ones you had to meet when you entered France the first two times) and have an ordinary Schengen tourist visa, you may travel to any Schengen state during the remainder of the 90 days left on your visa.  There is more detail in the answers [here](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/9646/3221) (as provided by the comment from Michael Hampton above).